# Internship in an EU country (Netherlands) with a German Visa and Residence Permit (non-EU citizen)

Tags: visa, internship

I'm currently studying in Germany and I have German residence permit, which also autorises me to do internships in Germany.

However, I have an opportunity to do one of my internships in another country of the European Union (Netherlands). I would like to know whether I should apply for a new Visa for the new country, or whether I'm able to do an internship with my German visa in Netherlands. I do not hold an European passport. (I am a Turkish passport holder).

Edit : This internship is a part of my curriculum and planned to be 4.5 months. Moreover, would I loose my German residence permit if I get one from Netherlands?

Comment: The exact requirements and procedure depends to some extent on the kind and duration of the internship and whether it's required for your studies (please add these details to your question). You will in any case almost certainly [need a residence permit (TWV)](https://ind.nl/en/work/working_in_the_Netherlands/Pages/Work-experience-as-trainee-or-apprentice.aspx) but you might be able to apply for it in the Netherlands (i.e. you don't need a visa or “MVV”).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This internship is a part of my curriculum and planned to be 4.5 months. Moreover, would I loose my German residence permit if I get one from Netherlands?

Comment: You wouldn't immediately loose your German residence permit. You could loose it if you stay longer out of the country but 4.5 months is allowed and resuming your studies should be no problem.

Comment: Is this 6 months period applies to total time spent outside Germany or in one time or does it resets for each year? For example can I stay abroad 4 months both in 2021 and 2022 with breaks?

Comment: I think it's only if you stay abroad 6 months at once that you would lose your residence permit. Some other countries have additional rules like no more than 4 months per year three years in a row but I don't know about Germany.